# How to start a thread in another class in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, methods

I have 3 classes as below. I cannot call a thread in another class but I declare this with main for it can be called.

I get the following error:

> **UseThreads.Thread1 'is a type' but is used like a 'variable'**

```
private void Mouse_Tracking()
{
    ///
}
```

How can I call to a thread in another class?

```
using System.Threading;

namespace UseThreads
{

public partial class from1 : Form
    {      

        private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread1));
            thread.Start();          

        }       
    }
}
```

Next One

```
using System.Threading;

namespace UseThreads
{
    class thread1
    {
        public void run()
        {
            int iterations = 10;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("From Thread1");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Last one

```
using System.Threading;

namespace UseThreads
{
    class thread2
    {
        public void run()
        {
            int iterations = 10;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("From Thread 2");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen?  How can I call a thread declared in a separate class?

Comment: Wait, isn't `ThreadStart` a delegate, and hence supposed to take the name of a method?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create an instance, and pass the run method:

```
var th = new thread1();
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(th.run));
```